# Magento 2 : Unable to Redirect in Checkout Page With Paypal Payment Pro

Tags: magento2, paypal, paypal-payments-pro

I have set up paypal payment pro with magento 2, during test transaction when i fill test credit card details and click on place order, it redirect me to same page.
I have check the log file in var/log debog.log and got this response

```
'result' => 
  array (
    'result' => '0',
    'respmsg' => 'Approved',
    'securetoken' => '9f7MCv6ww3kWePtSJepWWfAJZ',
    'securetokenid' => 'b432b4bbeb4e9070369da658ced5e718',
    'result_code' => '0',
  ),
) {"is_exception":false} []
```

Comment: Hello @Himanshu, I'm facing same problem in my magento 2. When I'm trying to place order using test credit card. Have you found any solution, why its happening. If you then please share the solution.